# android getting slow after a few days

Tags: android, tcp, android-asynctask

My app calls a request to server every 0.5s with TCP connection and it is also connected to hardwares for controlling led buttons (using jni library).

When the app is getting started, it starts TCP connection with server and maintains the connection until the app is turned off. Every 0.5s I send and received data packet from server using AsyncTask.
This is the code.

```
private class RequestToServer extends AsyncTask<byte[],Void,byte[]> {
    String dstAddress = "192.168.1.197";
    int dstPort = 8000;
    String response = "";

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(byte[]... params) {
        if(mSocket == null || !mSocket.isConnected()){
            mSocket =  new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(dstAddress, dstPort);
            try{
                mSocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
                mSocket.connect(socketAddress,5000);
            }catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            try {
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Connection Generated");
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "Connection Alive");
        }

        byte[] result = null;
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            if(mSocket.isConnected()){
                dataOutputStream.write(params[0]);
                Log.i(TAG,"send data : "+params[0]);
            }

            int bytesRead;
            if((bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                Log.i(TAG,"bytesRead size: "+bytesRead);
                result = new byte[bytesRead];
                result = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                buffer = null;
                Log.i(TAG,"data received~ : "+result);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

I am using two handler for keep requesting to server and communicating with hardwares (getting their status & controlling led status every 1s)

It works fine for a few days but after that, application is suddenly getting slow and sometimes led buttons keep blinking.

It doesn't have problem with memory when I saw the memory log.
Please let me know if you have any suspicious points or problem with upper code.

Comment: Hi do you mind adding why you want to connect with the server every 0.5 sec?

Comment: Because this app works for monitor and controller of some device. If some data is changed, it should be updated on the screen.

Comment: Then why not simply send data over *when* something has changed. Rather then constantly utilizing device's resources when most of the time nothing has changed.

Comment: I don't have authorization to server, so I can't know when data is changed.. is it gonna be a main problem to keep send/receive data from server? then why the problem happens after a few days?

Comment: Well, as I see it there could be three scenarios that may be hampering your connectivity. 1. It could be simply that your network is slow (not just the speed the pinging) however I don't think that is the case, 2. It could be because you are re-initializing your Socket each time you need to connect. In network communications often connecting with devices take longer than data transfers (protocols in place). So try connecting once and use that connection later. 3. It could be that GC is having trouble getting rid of all the extra resources.

Comment: Finally you might wanna think about using GCM or FCM from your server.
Since the architecture you are looking for must have downstream (server to client) connection rather than upstream (client to server).
Or you could make your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should check on GC and you're right. Downstream would be more suitable for this job. Just..It's huge work to solve this issue. If I can't find any other solution, I'll try it too.

Answer (score 0):

You will face this issue when the device is in sleep state.

Once the device's screen is switched off, the device goes to sleep state. This is done to save battery.

If you want to do some background operation when the device is in sleep state you need to acquire a partial wake lock and do the job.

Problem here is that you want to send this message every .5 secs hence you will practically never release the wake lock. So taking the wake lock will solve your problem but it will drain out the battery very fast.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

I don't know the exact use case of pulling the data every time from the server but you might consider using Server Push like GCM instead of constantly pulling the data.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. But I'm not sure that it is battery problem.  As I know, the screen is never switched off because it's always connected to power and it should be shown 24/7 according to requirements.